# Has anyone experienced an issue with not being able to create Asana tasks from Slack?

Tags: slack, asana, asana-connect

I have connected Asana with Slack and added Asana to the channel. I have the option to create an Asana task from Slack but when I select any of the options from the dropdown, it tells me Sorry, that didn’t work. Try again?

I have connected Asana with Slack and added Asana to the channel. I have the option to create an Asana task from Slack but when I select any of the options from the dropdown, it tells me Sorry, that didn’t work. Try again?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue too. I needed to integrate both apps from each "side." I had integrated Asana into Slack but never added Slack to the Asana side. Once I did, it began working for me.